# Obtain everything after one of these phrases in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to obtain everything after one of these phrases in a string in javascript.

The phrases are `call me` or `my name's`, or `my name is` or `my names` or `I am` or `I'm`

So I want everything after those phrases in the string.

I'm trying to do it like so, but it is capturing everything. Not only the text after.

```
/call\s+me(.*)|my\s+name\s+is(.*)|my\s+name's(.*)|my\s+names(.*)|Im(.*)|I\s+am(.*)|I'm(.*)/i.exec(string));
```

How can I do this properly?

Comment: can you give us a whole sample string where we can test the regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text after it will be in the capture groups. It will be in a different capture group depending on which prefix matched. So it would be better to put just the prefixes in the `|` alternatives, and just have a single capture group:

```
var result = str.match(/(?:call me|my name's|my name is|my names|I am|I'm)(.*)/)
```

Now `result[1]` will contain the text after the phrase.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/4xz0abkb/2/)

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain to me why match returns two values in the array and why the value I am looking for is not the zeroth one? I didn't know match returns an array, when does it? Why does it?

Comment: It is working fine in the regex tester regex.com, but when I run it in the console as `$('#searchInput').val().match(/(?:call me|my name's|my name is|my names|I am|I'm)(.*)/)[1]` I get can't read property 1 of null error. and $('#searchInput').val() is 'I am bob barker';

Comment: @user3743069 Try `( $('#searchInput').val().match(/(?:call me|my name's|my name is|my names|I am|I'm)(.*)/) )[1]`

Comment: @user3743069 The zeroth element of the array is the match of the whole regexp. The rest are the matches of the capture groups.

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. It works for me, see the jsfiddle demo

Answer (score 0):

Try a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=call me|my name's|my name is|my names|I am|I'm).*
```

See **[this demo](http://rubular.com/r/n0n77mJM1B)**.

#### Edit

This regex won't work on Javascript ( See @Barmar's answer for a Javascript use )

Comment: yes you're right, but I'll let this answer for other languages users.

Comment: The question is tagged with JavaScript.